# Expectancy and variance of combinatory random variable

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

I am struggling on a probability problem. Here is the theoretical layout:
Consider a set $\Omega$ with #$\Omega = N$ and a function $f:\Omega \rightarrow (0,1)$ such that $\sum\limits_{i  \epsilon \Omega} f(i) = p$

We pick a random subset S of $\Omega$ with #$S = n$ with $p\leq n$
Let's define the random variable $X = \sum\limits_{j  \epsilon S} f(j) $

Let's suppose that all subset of $\Omega$ have the same probability of being drawn. The question is to find the expectancy and variance of the random variable X

My first thought is to compute the following for k <= p
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=k) = \frac{\binom{p}{k}\binom{N-p}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}
$$
Now it is possible to get the expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^p \frac{\binom{p}{k}\binom{N-p}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}} k
$$
Which leads us to compute the following sum:
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}\binom{N-p}{n-k} k
$$
However, I am kind of stuck at this point. Same thing, I will need to compute the following to get to the variance
$$
\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}\binom{N-p}{n-k} k^2
$$

Anyone may hint me something ? I really feel I might use the derivation of $(1+x)^p(1+x)^{N-p}$ but cannot manage to find anything

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry but I disagree with everything past "My first thought".

Comment: Did you downvote my answer, by any chance?

Comment: @Did ive restored the +1 score now

Comment: @Lost1 Thanks for the upvote--which, I hope, was not mere compensation... :-)

Comment: @Did it is a very good solution to an interesting problem. just not sure if the OP took any notice.

Comment: thanks a lot! great solution

Comment: out of curiosity, was my reasoning completely wrong or only leading to a dead-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key to these computations is to rewrite $X$ as a sum over a fixed set, that is,
$$
X=\sum_{i\in\Omega}f(i)\mathbf 1_{i\in S}.
$$
If $S$ is chosen uniformly, then by symmetry, $P[i\in S]=n/N$ for each $i$. Thus,
$$
E[X]=\sum_{i\in\Omega}f(i)P[i\in S]=\sum_{i\in\Omega}f(i)n/N=pn/N.
$$
Likewise,
$$
X^2=\sum_{i\in\Omega}f(i)^2\mathbf 1_{i\in S}+\sum_{i\ne j}f(i)f(j)\mathbf 1_{i,j\in S}.
$$
If $S$ is chosen uniformly, then by symmetry, $P[i,j\in S]=n(n-1)/(N(N-1))$ for each $i\ne j$. Thus,
$$
E[X^2]=\sum_{i\in\Omega}f(i)^2P[i\in S]+\sum_{i\ne j}f(i)f(j)P[i,j\in S],
$$
that is,
$$
E[X^2]=rn/N+(p^2-r)n(n-1)/(N(N-1)),
$$
where
$$
r=\sum_{i\in\Omega}f(i)^2.
$$
The variance follows, as
$$
\mathrm{var}(X)=\frac{n(N-n)}{N(N-1)}\left(r-\frac{p^2}N\right).
$$

Comment: except the trivial case when $N=1$ or $0$?

Comment: @Lost1 I guess that even when N=1, E[X] is correct (but of course not var(X), except if one uses ad hoc and not very interesting conventions about 0/0).